org-table-align slow, projectile-find-file-hook-function might be the issue?
The function org-table-align is slow on my new computer.
It looks like the culprit is projectile-find-file-hook-function but I don't understand how that would feature in the alignment.
profiler-report:
        2294  78% - command-execute
    2171  74%  - funcall-interactively
    2114  72%   - execute-extended-command
    2114  72%    - command-execute
    2087  71%     - funcall-interactively
    2048  70%      - org-table-align
    1108  37%       - org-string-width
    1079  36%        - record-window-buffer
    1069  36%         - projectile-track-known-projects-find-file-hook
     443  15%          + projectile-project-p
     399  13%          + projectile-add-known-project
     225   7%          + projectile-project-root
      14   0%        + #<compiled -0x15fe1bb73b163c78>
       6   0%          version<
       6   0%        + #<compiled -0x1c762795c674990f>
     908  31%       - cl-mapcar
     907  31%        - cl--mapcar-many
     907  31%         - org-table--align-field
     891  30%          - org-string-width
     879  30%           - record-window-buffer
     874  29%            - projectile-track-known-projects-find-file-hook
     333  11%             + projectile-add-known-project
     292   9%             + projectile-project-p
     244   8%             + projectile-project-root
       1   0%            + push-window-buffer-onto-prev
       8   0%             #<compiled -0x15fe1bb73b163c78>
       2   0%             version<
      35   1%      + profiler-report
      27   0%     + byte-code
      22   0%   + ido-kill-buffer
      17   0%   + next-line
      12   0%   + previous-line
       4   0%   + org-cycle
       1   0%     delete-other-windows
     123   4%  + byte-code

Version information:

emacs version 29.3
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
org version 9.6.15

Thanks for any suggestions!
